# How do I create a ranking across multiple indexes in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am working on using full text search in Postgres but I am not sure how to rank results that come from two indexes.

The case looks something like this:

```
TableA
--------------
title
titleSearchVector
ownerId

TableB
--------------
title
titleSearchVector
ownerId
```

I want to search based on the ownerId from both tables and put the results in one list sorted with `TableA.title` above `TableB.title`.

Is it fine to set rankings across columns like this?

```
setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(TableA.title,'')), 'A')

...

setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(TableB.title,'')), 'B')
```

I want them to be combined into one list and for `TableB` results to rank lower than `TableA` for the same search string.

Something feels a little off about this and doesn't look valid. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is your only requirement that titles from `TableA` appear before titles from `TableB`, both sorted in rank order within their own table?

Comment: @MikeOrganek Sort of. I want to combine the results of both into one list so I want to keep the order when I merge them if that makes sense. I was trying to come up with a way that TableB would always rank lower given the same search string.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `setweight()` to accomplish this.

My approach would be:

```
with combined as (
  select 'A' as tsource, title, titleSearchVector, ownerId
    from tableA
  union all
  select 'B' as tsource, title, titleSearchVector, ownerId
    from tableB
)
select title, titleSearchVector, ownerId, 
       ts_rank(titleSearchVector, to_tsquery(?)) as rank
  from combined
 where ownerId = ?
 order by tsource, rank desc;
```

Comment: While I think this would work for my initial suggestion, I ended up using the ranking because I had another column in TableA that needed to be ranked below the column in TableB.  Wasn't in my original question but worked well after I added that extra column